# Locked out of the job application portal

Tags: communication, job-search, hiring-process, united-states, rejection

I applied to a job position where I got rejected and no communication was made from the company. Job position was re-opened around 1 month later, so I reapplied.

I believed (at least at the moment) that you can reapply for the same position as long as you were not called in for interviews before rejection, in which case you should wait for 6-12 months to reapply.

Today, I read [this discussion](https://www.indeed.com/forum/gen/Career-Advice/many-jobs-do-you-apply-average-week/t290207) on indeed and noticed  someone mentioning that if a person doesn't qualify for the job then the recruiter won't contact them upon rejecting their application. There was I requirement that I was missing and I hoped that it might be overlooked if they find my profile interesting. Anyways after reading the article I decided to withdraw my application only to find out that I am locked out of the companies job portal.

Now, I want to contact and clarify my side of story as the company does have other position which were not my first choice but are good and I would love to be considered for them. So my question is that **what can be the pros and cons of contacting and informing the company about the same in hope for then being able to apply to other positions?**

Comment: No company is good enough to excuse a crappy and/or onerous application portal (unless that's what the job's for - maybe).  I once told a recruiter that I no longer wished to be considered for a certain fortune 250 transportation company because after being "sold" that this company was so great that people endure the strict requirements for applying and a lengthy process, I discovered upon attempting to apply that it was a classic ASP site (in 2014). I told him, "I question the judgement of any company that relies on such bad software (and it was VERY bad) on such old tech."

Comment: What do you mean 'locked out'. What does it actually say when you try to apply? Maybe it is simply a matter of resetting your login, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I applied to a job position where I got rejected and no communication was made from the company

Likely you didn't pass the keyword scan by the ATS (Application Tracking System).  In my experience what tends to happen is you remain in limbo on the role until it closes.

If you have tried to apply again (and it's the same role and not reposted as a new one), it'll either reject it saying you have already applied, or just sit with nothing happening.

It's unusual to be locked out, you should try the link to reset password.  It's unlikely you are actually locked out, unless your submission(s) have been suspect.

I would reach out to them, ideally phone someone so you can actually talk to someone, tell them of your issue (but don't mention how you don't meet their criteria, let them figure that out) and see if they can either unlock your profile, or accept your resume in another way.

Just make sure you are courteous, but don't be too pushy, and make sure they understand you are contacting them due to issues with the ATS, don't let them think you are trying to sidestep their process.

You have nothing to lose, and maybe a job to gain

Comment: I tried resetting the password. The fields were set to disabled (I looked at the html source) in the link I received to reset the password. I highly doubt the submission should be suspect but you never know. Anyways I will try talking to them and see what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure this company is a good fit for you then you have a few things to think about. ***Did the portal system give you any additional information on how to proceed or was it vague and just said your locked out?***

If it didn't indicate anything in terms of next steps, you might well need to contact them to sort it out if you're that interested in working with them.

As for your request for pros and cons in getting in touch with them;

#### Pros

1. You get in touch and are unlocked from the system.
2. You get an interview.
3. You get a job offer.
4. You accept and get the job.

#### Cons

1. They may or may not say they'll unlock your account and may or may not interview you for a job and may or may not offer it to you.

*The worst thing that can happen is you ultimately don't get the job or may not even have your account unlocked.*

You can always ask and find out what happened to the account. ***You do need to weigh up the time you spend trying to sort this compared to the benefits of looking elsewhere.*** If you're really interested then all you can do is politely ask.

Comment: The portal was very much vague. I also appreciate the suggestion about weighing the cost of each action.